# Sort method and indexes

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, underscore.js, fixed-data-table

I'm trying fixed data table in my project.

But I have a problem about sorting.

Here I'm using this example:
https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/examples/old/SortExample.js

It sorts by desc or asc.
But I have problem about it.

For example when I first sort it by name,it brings this sorted array.

id:2 name:Mary

id:4 name:Mary

id:5 name:Mary

id:1 name:Anna

id:3 name:Anna

That is ok.But when I sort it again by name desc.It brings.

id:4 name:Mary

id:2 name:Mary

id:5 name:Mary

id:3 name:Anna

id:1 name:Anna

Ok it sort by name but the problem is:It change the index of the same values.For example it brings (id:4 name:Mary) to the  first line.

But when I first sorted,it bringed (id:2 name:Mary).

Why it changes the same values indexes?

Is there a problem about sort method?

EDIT:here is my full code:

```
var FixedDataTable = require('fixed-data-table');
var React = require('react');

var Column = FixedDataTable.Column;
var Table = FixedDataTable.Table;

var SortTypes = {
  ASC: 'ASC',
  DESC: 'DESC',
};

function renderDate(/*object*/ cellData) {
  return <span>{cellData.toLocaleString()}</span>;
}

var SortExample = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      rows: [{"id":"1","name":"Mary"},{"id":"2","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"3","name":"Mary"},{"id":"4","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"5","name":"Mary"},{"id":"6","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"7","name":"Mary"},{"id":"8","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"9","name":"Mary"},{"id":"10","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"11","name":"Mary"},{"id":"12","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"13","name":"Mary"},{"id":"14","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"15","name":"Mary"},{"id":"16","name":"Felix"},
                   {"id":"17","name":"Mary"},{"id":"18","name":"Felix"} ,
                   {"id":"19","name":"Mary"},{"id":"20","name":"Felix"}],sortBy: 'id',
      sortDir: null,
    };
  },

  _rowGetter(rowIndex) {
    return this.state.rows[rowIndex];
  },

  _sortRowsBy(cellDataKey) {
    var sortDir = this.state.sortDir;
    var sortBy = cellDataKey;
    if (sortBy === this.state.sortBy) {
      sortDir = this.state.sortDir === SortTypes.ASC ? SortTypes.DESC : SortTypes.ASC;
    } else {
      sortDir = SortTypes.DESC;
    }

    var rows = this.state.rows.slice();
    rows.sort((a, b) => {
      var sortVal = 0;
      if (a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) {
        sortVal = 1;
      }
      if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) {
        sortVal = -1;
      }

      if (sortDir === SortTypes.DESC) {
        sortVal = sortVal * -1;
      }

      return sortVal;
    });

    this.setState({
      rows,
      sortBy,
      sortDir,
    });
  },

  _renderHeader(label, cellDataKey) {
    return (
      <a onClick={this._sortRowsBy.bind(null, cellDataKey)}>{label}</a>
    );
  },

  render() {
    var sortDirArrow = '';

    if (this.state.sortDir !== null){
      sortDirArrow = this.state.sortDir === SortTypes.DESC ? ' ↓' : ' ↑';
    }

    return (
      <Table
        rowHeight={50}
        rowGetter={this._rowGetter}
        rowsCount={this.state.rows.length}
        headerHeight={50}
        width={1000}
        height={500}
        {...this.props}>
        <Column
          headerRenderer={this._renderHeader}
          label={'id' + (this.state.sortBy === 'id' ? sortDirArrow : '')}
          width={100}
          dataKey='id'
        />
        <Column
          headerRenderer={this._renderHeader}
          label={'First Name' + (this.state.sortBy === 'name' ? sortDirArrow : '')}
          width={200}
          dataKey='name'
        />

      </Table>
    );
  },
});









ReactDOM.render(
 <SortExample/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Please post your code showing how the sorting module is initiated and used.

Comment: @EthanBierlein - Thanks for the correction. I've removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Unable to duplicate the problem.**

The sorting function appears to work correctly and as expected.

**Update:**
The snippet was modified to alternate sort direction on each call. However, the results were the same, i.e., the function works correctly and as expected. In addition, the [FixedDataTable demo](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/example-sort.html) sorts hundreds of records any direction correctly.

The sorting function is found on lines 53-65:

```
var rows = this.state.rows.slice();
rows.sort((a, b) => {
     var sortVal = 0;
     if (a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) {
          sortVal = 1;
     }
     if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) {
        sortVal = -1;
     }
     if (sortDir === SortTypes.DESC) {
         sortVal = sortVal * -1;
     }
     return sortVal;
});
```

A test array sorted repeatedly always returns the same data in the same order:

2, Mary

4, Mary

5, Mary

1, Anna

3, Anna

There could be a problem with OP's code (not shown) or how the sorted data is copied back to the original array, i.e., setState().

**Show the code snippet and click run to try.**

```js
var i, sortBy, SortTypes, state,count=0;


SortTypes = {
  ASC: 'ASC',
  DESC: 'DESC'
};

sortBy = 'name';


function test( sortDir ) {

  var rows = state.rows.slice();
  rows.sort((a, b) => {
    var sortVal = 0;
    if (a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) {
      sortVal = 1;
    }
    if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) {
      sortVal = -1;
    }
    if (sortDir === SortTypes.DESC) {
      sortVal = sortVal * -1;
    }
    return sortVal;
  });

  count++;
  document.getElementById('stdout').innerHTML += 
    'SORT: ' + count + ' ' + sortDir + '\n' +JSON.stringify(rows, null, '  ') + '\n\n';
}



// example data
state = {
  rows: [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Anna'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Mary'
  }, {
    id: '30',
    name: 'Anna'
  }, {
    id: '40',
    name: 'Mary'
  }, {
    id: '100',
    name: 'Mary'
  }]
};


for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
  test( 'ASC' );
  test( 'DESC' );
}
```

```html
Results of sorting the test array multiple times:<br>

<xmp id="stdout"></xmp>
```

Comment: Actually the problem occurs when I first sort by asc,after desc and after asc..... and after desc.So when I sort repeatedly.And when there are too much data with same value.For example 10 name with "Mary" and 10 name with "Anna".

Comment: @javauser35 - Modified the test code to alternate sort direction, but the results were the same. Unable to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Hey Roberto.I added my full code for you.Can you look at it ?

Answer (score 0):

i thinks this will fix your problem,
**i used Lodash library**

```
`var data = [
   {
    id:1,
    name: "Anna"
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: "Anna"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: "Mary"
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: "Mary"
  },
  {
    id:5,
    name: "Mary"
  }
];
var sortArray = _.sortBy(data, function(o) { return o.name; });
var reverseSortArray = _.cloneDeep(sortArray).reverse();
console.log("sort Array: ", sortArray);
console.log("reverse Sort Array", reverseSortArray);`
```

Comment: Did you catch my problem ? Why it is happening when I sort repeatedly?